# JSON string acting funny on server end

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am almost pulling my hair in frustration having tried to sort the issue I'm having.
I'm trying to use javascript to send some data to a PHP server while making use of JSON.
From what I experience, once the string hits the PHP server and I use the json_decode PHP command to decode the string back to its json format, it fails. It fails as I cannot get the size of the associative array json_decode is meant to return.
Funny enough, if I rather save the string to my database to a column of blob type, and then later try to repeat the process of using json_decode and making use of the associative array it returns, I get positive results.

Kindly see a little bit of the code involved.

### Javascript Code

```
var products = {
        product: [],
        companyId: ""
    };

products.companyId = nameofCompany;

for(var c=0; c<count; c++)
{
    var product = {
        productItems: []
    };
    productTitle=document.getElementById('productTitle' + c).innerHTML;
    product.productItems.push({ "productTitle" : productTitle});
    products.product.push({ "product" : product});
}

var JSONObject = new Object;
    JSONObject = products;
    JSONstring = JSON.stringify(JSONObject);
    addNewProduct(JSONstring, 'addNewProduct')

//make ajax calls to PHP server here. I have shorted it to show that I am passing the string

function addNewProduct(inputStr, fieldStr)
{

    inputValue = encodeURIComponent(inputValue);
    fieldID = encodeURIComponent(fieldID);
    cache.push("inputStr=" + inputStr + "&fieldStr=" + fieldStr);
    if ((xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 0) && cache.length > 0)
    {
        xmlHttp.open("POST", phpServerAddress, true);
    }
 }
```

### PHP Code

the below code will not work as it returns a value of 0 for the sizeof() command. However if I save the 
$_POST['inputStr'] to a database column of blob type and then try to read and do this same code, it works 
perfectly well

```
if(isset($_POST['inputStr']))
{

    $jsonStrArr= (json_decode($_POST['inputStr'], true));
    die sizeof($jsonStrArr);
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `inputValue = encodeURIComponent(inputValue);` shouldn't that be `inputStr`?

Comment: One tip: using firebug in Firefox you should see xhr request in the console. Open them up and see what's posted raw and split up into variables.

Comment: generally we uses JSON to send complex data structure form server to client's browser. Why do you need to create data structure on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, I assume it's because its quite large and might be spread over several files. As noted before:encodeURIComponent(inputValue) should be inputStr.

Here is a working php page, maybe you can use it to add your code and trace what goes wrong.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["object"])){
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_GET);
    var_dump($_POST["object"]);
    var_dump(json_decode($_POST["object"]));
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var myObj={value1:"value1",value2:"value2"};
        var someOtherVal="hello there";
        var postString="object=" + escape(JSON.stringify(myObj))
            +"&someOtherval="+escape(someOtherVal);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "index.php" ,true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(this.readyState != 4){
        return;
            }
            if (this.status === 200 || this.status == 304) {
                document.getElementById("output")
                    .innerHTML=this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhr.send(postString);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, my code actually is complete but putting it up here would have taken so much space.
However I was able to finally get the issue resolved. 
Resolved it by writing the JSON.stringify value to a file where I noticed the value had escape characters in it. Using stripslashes on the PHP server simply helped out.
All the same thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All,
Thanks for your response. However I was able to finally get the issue resolved. Resolved it by writing the JSON.stringify value to a file where I noticed the value had escape characters in it. Using stripslashes on the PHP server simply helped out. All the same thanks